# Create a "wizard" for Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

The requirement would be to build a wizard for a Dynamics CRM 2011 environment, that is, some sort of user interface that guides the user to complete a certain task.

My idea is something like this:

1. By clicking on a custom ribbon's button a new window (hosted ASP.NET application) is opened.
2. From a javascript web resource retrieve the result from the ASP.NET page (`Response`).
3. Use the results to perform the task (e.g. sets some fields).

Does this make sense?

Comment: Dialogs doesn't work for you in this case?

Comment: Do you mean the javascript prompt, alert, ecc.? I think it would look a bit weird for a wizard.

Comment: I mean Dialog Workflows.

Comment: @Sxntk Thanks for mentioning that, I'll have to take a deeper look into them.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the Dialog process is for